# All compiled artifacts in separate directory?

Tags: c, makefile

I'd like to write a simple Makefile which creates all `*.o`, `*.so`, and binary files in a build directory, possibly `build/`.

Is there a straightforward way of doing this in a Makefile? I'm on Linux, Ubuntu 14.04.

The linked question puts all `*.o` artifacts in a build directory, but not the executables themselves. To be clear, I'd like to hit `make` and have all items compiled and stored in `build/`.

Comment: you can specify a outputfile with `-o` which can also include a directory.

Comment: Is there a way to set that in my Makefile so if I just run `make`, everything works as planned? I just want to set some default somewhere so that all binaries end up there.

Comment: see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552575/gnu-make-pattern-to-build-output-in-different-directory-than-src)

Comment: @jayant That doesn't address my problem: I'd like all `*.o` files _and_ the executables placed in a build directory.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay maybe I misunderstood. But in that question all his artefacts are stored in `OBJDIR_DEBUG` which happens to be `Debug`, you want to call it `build`. That's why I thought that link would help. Otherwise to answer your question, yes you can use the Makefile to put all you build artefacts in a separate directory.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use GNU make, something like:

```
O     ?= build
OBJS  := $(patsubst %.c,$(O)/%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
SOS   := $(O)/<you know better than me>
EXECS := $(O)/<you know better than me>

all: $(OBJS) $(SOS) $(EXECS)

$(OBJS): $(O)/%.o: %.c
    mkdir -p $(O); \
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(SOS): ...

$(EXECS): ...
```

should be close to what you want. As I do not know which `*.so` and executables you want to build and how, I just indicate a possibility for the rule that builds the `*.o`. It should be easy to adapt to the other targets.

If you type `make`, the `build` sub-directory will be created if it does not exist. If you type `make O=foo`, the `foo` sub-directory will be created (if it does not exist) and be used instead of `build`.

`$(OBJS): $(O)/%.o: %.c` is a static pattern rule. In case it is not clear enough, the GNU make documentation will tell you everything about them.