# What's missing: make: *** No rule to make target

Tags: c++, makefile

I'd love to move my C++ environment away from Visual Studio on Windows to building simple software on MacOS or Ubuntu.

My test project for doing so (am small Snake game) contains the following structure

```
Snake
|- bin
|- data
|- docs
|- lib
|- inc
   |- application
         |- app_main.h
         |- app_game_state.h
         |- app_load_map_state.h
         |- app_main_menu_state.h
         |- app_play_state.h
         |- app_shutdown_state.h
         |- app_startup_state.h
         |- app_state.h
         |- app_unload_map_state.h
   |- core
   |- graphics
   |- gui
   |- logic
   |- world
|- intern
   |- build
      |- obj
   |- tests
   |- src
      |- application
         |- Makefile
         |- main.cpp
         |- app_main.cpp
         |- app_game_state.cpp
         |- app_load_map_state.cpp
         |- app_main_menu_state.cpp
         |- app_play_state.cpp
         |- app_shutdown_state.cpp
         |- app_startup_state.cpp
         |- app_state.cpp
         |- app_unload_map_state.cpp
      |- core
      |- graphics
      |- gui
      |- logic
      |- world
```

The `Makefile` is structured as follows:

```
IDIR = ../../../inc
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -I$(IDIR)

ODIR = ../../build/obj
LDIR = ../../../lib

VPATH = ../core:../graphics/:../gui/:../logic/:../world/

_DEPS = app_game_state.h app_load_map_state.h app_main.h app_main_menu_state.h app_play_state.h app_shutdown_state.h app_startup_state.h app_state.h app_unload_map_state.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = main.o app_game_state.o app_load_map_state.o app_main.o app_main_menu_state.o app_play_state.o app_shutdown_state.o app_startup_state.o app_state.o app_unload_map_state.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

$(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

main: $(OBJ)
    g++ -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

My aim was to port what I've learned from [this excellent beginner tutorial on Makefiles](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) to my own architecture. The tutorials `make` command is running without problems on my machine. So I guess I've missed something.

As I'm being new to Makefiles, it's a bit hard for me to grasp the concepts. Even though I thought to understand the basics, the make command returns a `make: *** No rule to make target '../../build/obj/main.o', needed by 'main'.  Stop.` error when I run make from `intern/src/application`

To solve the problem I tried to apply the solution from [gcc makefile error: "No rule to make target ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834748/gcc-makefile-error-no-rule-to-make-target) to my code - yet without success.

Where's the error in my Makefile and what did I not understand?

**Edit:**
Here's the make output with the -d flag enabled (had to remove some code from the beginning due to stackoverflows limitation of symbols in a message)

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `Makefile'...
...
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Makefile.S'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.S,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.S,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.S'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.S'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.S'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
   Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makefile.S'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.mod'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Makefile.mod'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.mod,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.mod,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.mod'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.mod'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.mod'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makefile.c'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makefile.cc'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makefile.C'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makefile.cpp'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makefile.p'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makefile.f'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makefile.F'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makefile.m'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makefile.r'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makefile.s'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makefile.S'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makefile.mod'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.sh'.
  Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Makefile.sh'.
   Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.sh,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.sh,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.sh'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.sh'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.sh'.
  No implicit rule found for `Makefile'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `Makefile'.
 No need to remake target `Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `main'.
 File `main' does not exist.
  Considering target file `../../build/obj/main.o'.
   File `../../build/obj/main.o' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for `../../build/obj/main.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `main.cpp'.
   Trying rule prerequisite `../../../inc/app_game_state.h'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.c'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.cc'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.C'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.cpp'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.p'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.f'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.F'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.m'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.r'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.s'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.S'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.mod'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.o,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.o,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `main.cpp'.
   Trying rule prerequisite `../../../inc/app_game_state.h'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../../inc/app_game_state.h'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `app_game_state.h'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../../inc/app_game_state.h,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `app_game_state.h'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../../inc/RCS/app_game_state.h,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `app_game_state.h'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../../inc/RCS/app_game_state.h'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `app_game_state.h'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../../inc/s.app_game_state.h'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `app_game_state.h'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../../inc/SCCS/s.app_game_state.h'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.c'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.c'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.y'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.l'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.w'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.w'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.c,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.c,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.y'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.y'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.y,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.y,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.y'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.y'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.y'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.l'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.l'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.l,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.l,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.l'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.l'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.l'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.w'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.w'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.w,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.w,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.w'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.w'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.w'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.w'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.cc'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.cc'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.cc,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.cc,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.cc'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.cc'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.cc'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.C'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.C'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.C'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.C,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.C'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.C,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.C'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.C'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.C'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.C'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.C'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.C'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.cpp'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.cpp'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.cpp,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.cpp,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.cpp'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.cpp'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.cpp'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.p'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.p'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.web'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.p,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.p,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.p'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.p'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.p'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.web'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.web'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.web,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.web,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.web'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.web'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.web'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.f'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.f'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.F'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.r'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.f,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.f,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.f'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.f'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.f'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.F'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.F'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.F'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.F,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.F'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.F,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.F'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.F'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.F'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.F'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.F'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.F'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.r'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.r'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
     Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.l'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.r,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.r,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.r'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.r'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.r'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.F'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.m'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.m'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.ym'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.lm'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.m'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.m,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.m'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.m,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.m'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.m'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.m'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.m'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.m'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.m'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.ym'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.ym'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.ym'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.ym,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.ym'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.ym,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.ym'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.ym'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.ym'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.ym'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.ym'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.ym'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.lm'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.lm'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.lm'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.lm,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.lm'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.lm,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.lm'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.lm'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.lm'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.lm'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.lm'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.lm'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.r'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.s'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.s'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.S'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.s,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.s,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.s'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.s'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.s'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.S'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.S'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.S,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.S,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.S'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.S'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `main.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.S'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.S'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.mod'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../../build/obj/main.mod'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/main.mod,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.mod,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/RCS/main.mod'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/s.main.mod'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `main.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `../../build/obj/SCCS/s.main.mod'.
   No implicit rule found for `../../build/obj/main.o'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `../../build/obj/main.o'.
  Must remake target `../../build/obj/main.o'.
```

Comment: Wow, that `Makefile` seems rather complicated to me. You could try to specify the build rules for each `.o` file separately (as I'm not sure what your `OBJ` variable contains). For example: `main.o: <newline> $(CC) main.c` And then `main: main.o`

Comment: Make sure that the filename of your makefile is indeed `Makefile`.

Comment: you could use CMake to get a cross-platform "makefile"

Comment: @ForceBru: Looks pretty simple to me. You shouldn't define build rules for every `.o` separately. OP is doing it right.

Comment: Can't see what's wrong here. Turn verbose output on and see how everything's being resolved.

Comment: Please provide the full output. Perhaps it's just a compilation error.

Comment: @IgorR. I added the output of make with the -d flag enabled

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I'm no expert in Makefiles and since the OP say they're a beginner, I thought it could help to do this the easiest (but requiring more writing) way. At least, this is what I do when my Makefile doesn't work correctly, and this often helps.

Comment: @Force: The easiest way does not require more writing

Comment: Mmm nope dunno sorry. Everything looks fine to me at a glance, but the debug output clearly shows the right rule isn't being found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependencies for the rule

```
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

are not satisfied: while `make` finds `main.cpp` OK it doesn't find the dependencies from `$(DEPS)`. You can fix the problem by pointing `IDIR` to the correct directory:

```
IDIR = = ../../../inc/application
```

Admittedly, the error message isn't entirely helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this approach and it works. Yet I wonder: Thought it would work since I included the libraries by e.g. `#include "applications/app_main.h` in the .cpp files... So the inc/applications inc/core etc. all have to be included directly?

Comment: @VanGoghsCoffee: `make` doesn't look at the content of the files. Just because you include the files with a path doesn't make `make` look for the dependencies in a different location. If you want to get the dependencies determine based on how they are included, have a look at the dependency options of the compiler (e.g., `-M` and family).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That wasn't clear to me. Thought `inc/` would work as a root path to all of my header directories.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your below implicit rule is not working.

```
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

But, in it's place, please try using the following [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) to make the object files:

```
$(OBJ): $(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

A very similar question has been asked here - [GNU Make pattern to build output in different directory than src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552575/gnu-make-pattern-to-build-output-in-different-directory-than-src). I tried that answer for the directory set up you have shown and it worked.

Please let me know if I should have added this as a comment. I couldn't make out which was right.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this approach. Now the error message is `make: *** No rule to make target '../../../inc/app_game_state.h', needed by '../../build/obj/main.o'.  Stop.`

Comment: True, I missed that. As answered by @VanGoghsCoffee you will also have to modify IDIR accordingly. So, apart from getting more accurate errors from 'make', there is no reason to use a static pattern rule in place of your implicit rule.