# Generic Makefile build directory error

Tags: makefile, directory, gnu-make

I have the following directory structure for a dummy C project.

```
.
├── inc
│   ├── getmsg.c
│   └── getmsg.h
├── makefile
└── src
    └── main.c
```

My current generic Makefile is below,

```
TARGET = main

# finds all .c files, inc/getmsg.c src/main.c
SOURCES := $(shell find * -name *.c)
# converts all .c files to .o files, inc/getmsg.o src/main.o
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:.c=.o)  
# directories that contain .h files for gcc -I flag, inc/
HEADERS := $(dir $(shell find * -name *.h))

CC     = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c99 -iquote "$(HEADERS)"

all: $(TARGET)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -rf $(shell find * -name *.o) $(TARGET)
```

This all compiles fine however it just dumps the .o files into the same directory as its corresponding .c file.

What I would like to do is have all object files put into a build directory. To do this I change the `OBJECTS` to `OBJECTS := $(patsubst %,build/%,$(notdir $(SOURCES:.c=.o)))` which lists the files `build/getmsg.o build/main.o`. Then I set the `%.o` target to `build/%.o: %.c`.

This however returns `No rule to make target 'build/getmsg.o'`. So the make file is unable to build the .o files. What am I missing here?

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552575/gnu-make-pattern-to-build-output-in-different-directory-than-src

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GNU Make pattern to build output in different directory than src](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552575/gnu-make-pattern-to-build-output-in-different-directory-than-src)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
%.o: %.c
```

to

```
build/%.o: %.c
```

Comment: Thats what I tired and it gave me the "No rule" error.

Comment: Whoops, missed that part! Check out the following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639794/getting-make-to-create-object-files-in-a-specific-directory