# Makefile - link input file from folder

Tags: makefile

I try to compile a project with generated object stored in a sub directory :

```
myproject:
|
src: .cpp, .cpp ...
  |
  release: .o, .o ...
```

Here's a part of Makefile:

```
SRC     ?= src
OBJ_PATH = $(SRC)/Release
vpath %.o $(OBJ_PATH)

...

OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJ_PATH)/,obj1.o obj2.o )

all: build

obj1.o: $(SRC)/Manager.cpp
$(EXEC) $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CCFLAGS) $(GNCD_FLGS) -c $(<) -o $(OBJ_PATH)/$@ #-o $@ -c $<

obj2.o: $(SRC)/Synth.cpp
$(EXEC) $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CCFLAGS) $(GNCD_FLGS) $(DEFS) -c $(<) -o $(OBJ_PATH)/$@ #-o $@ -c $<


myApp:  obj1.o obj2.o
$(EXEC) $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(GNCD_FLGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $+ $(LIBS)
$(EXEC) mkdir -p $(OBJ_PATH)/$(TRGT_ARCH)/$(TRGT_OS)/$(BLD_TP)
$(EXEC) cp $@ $(OBJ_PATH)/$(TRGT_ARCH)/$(TRGT_OS)/$(BLD_TP)

$(OBJECTS) : Stt.h

build: myApp

run: build
$(EXEC) ./myApp
```

..but i got an error link:

```
Could not open input file 'obj1.o' 
Makefile:86: recipe for target 'myApp' failed
```

So it seems couldn't find object in src/Release dir;

any ideas ?

thank's

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552575/gnu-make-pattern-to-build-output-in-different-directory-than-src ?

Comment: Yes, it's sounds interesting but in my case i need to create objects from project source and also an external lib. So i'm not sure to get this syntax to be able to link both objects ..

Answer (score 0):

Your recipe for myApp use `$+`, which list the prerequisites. It expands in `obj1.o obj2.o`. But you build obj1.o and obj2.o in `$(OBJ_PATH)`. So the linker try to find the objects in the root directory, but cannot find them, since they are in `$(OBJ_PATH)`.
Since your recipe explicitely lists them (with `$(OBJS)`), you do not need the automatic variable.

**Sidenote**

According to Paul's Second rule of Makefiles, it is best that every rule updates a file corresponding exactly to the target name (including the path part) (in other words, always use `$@` in the recipe), in order to always know which is the exact file updated.
In your case, if you want to build the objects files in OBJ_PATH, you could use a rule of the form `$(OBJ_PATH)/obj.o` for each.
You could also replace the dependency of myApp by `$(OBJS)`, and use the automatic variable (btw, is there a reason why you prefer `$+` over `$^` (does the same thing but do not conserv duplicates in the prerequisites list) ?).

Comment: Hi VannTen, i modified like $(OBJ_PATH)/obj1.o: $(SRC)/Manager.cpp ...and for myApp,  $(EXEC) cp $@ $(OBJ_PATH)/$(TRGT_ARCH) become $(EXEC) cp $@ $(TRGT_ARCH)/.. Thank's for your explanations :)